# VS2013 build using Release vs Debug MVC5

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

I have converted MVC4 to MVC5, all works well except for one model.  If I build the application on Debug (showing in the drop down menu) I don't get an error; however when I change Debug to Release I get this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ModelA' could not be found
```

If I build the old MVC4 in VS2012 using Release, I don't get any error!!  Any idea why I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was in the project file, some of the references were pointing to the old project directory.  Now it is working, I hope this could help someone.